# Java method to return string from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

There is a main method which have different textfields with the same KeyListener class

```
 textfield1.addKeyListener( new TextfieldKeyListener() );
 textfield2.addKeyListener( new TextfieldKeyListener() );
 textfield3.addKeyListener( new TextfieldKeyListener() );
```

The KeyListener class is something like this.

```
public class TextfieldKeyListener implements KeyListener
{

 public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e )
 {

  //This method should get a string from any given textfield.
  system.out.println(textfield.getText().toString() );
 }

}
```

Is it possible that a KeyListener class takes a string from a textfield and print it?
One way is that three textfields should have three KeyListener classes but here should be one KeyListener class for all the textfields.

Comment: You might want to use the `getSource()` method of the `KeyEvent` object to get the source (the `JTextField` in this case) where the event occured.

Comment: Ok. But how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: `e.getSource()` returns the reference to the `JTextField` instance where the event occured. You can cast the return value to `JTextField` and access the methods like `getText()`. You can write code like `((JTextField)e.getSource()).getText()`.

Answer (score 2):

```java
public class TextfieldKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if (src instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) src;
            System.out.println(textField.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource--)